# How to rotate footnote with listings?

Tags: rotation, latex, tikz, lstlisting

How can I rotate footnote, which contains a listings?

Currently my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings} %kod programów
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox{180}{\footnote{Trzeba zastosować
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}
            \draw[stealth-]\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

Sketch:

[image: Reversed sketch - example]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like? Where is a footnote supposed to be after it is rotated 180 degrees? At the top of the page? What about the footnotemarker?

Comment: Yes, yes, sure. I want to have it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Look now, I send a example sketch - it is reversed in Paint.

Comment: Can you show the whole page? I still have no idea where this is supposed to go

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://www.overleaf.com/read/yttrxcfppfvm

Yes, but due to making bigger document, I can demonstrate You only an example page. As You can see, here footnote is on the end of the page - which is correct, but not rotated by 180 degrees...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I must add that code of this page is placed on Overleaf (I forgot about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the content of the footnote like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings} %kod programów
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\LstBox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\LstBox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\draw[stealth-]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

some text\footnote{\rotatebox{180}{Trzeba zastosować {\usebox{\LstBox}}}}


\end{document}
```

[image]